# Is it possible to exclude the commit message from git commits from SHA Algorithm?

Tags: git

Is it possible to exclude the commit message from git commits from SHA Algorithm?
Then the commit message could be easily changed after error/lack of information was found.

Comment: The -m parameter allows you to specify the commit message. If you leave this parameter out, your default editor is started and you have to enter the message in the editor.

Comment: @gpullen The OP is asking about whether preventing the commit message from being baked into the SHA is possible, not how a commit message is specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can exclude this, but there is git notes, which is designed to do this.